# How do I use wstool recursively?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Repository `A` contains a `a.rosinstall` file that contains it's source dependencies.
Within `a.rosinstall` there is:

- Repository `B`
- Repository `C`

It happens that `B` also contains a rosinstall file, `b.rosinstall` that has repository `D` inside.

Is there a way with `wstool` to merge recursively so that every indirect dependency of A (`E`) is also cloned?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314789/how-do-i-use-wstool-recursively?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2019-02-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not one of the use-cases that `wstool` covers.

Repositories are almost completely opaque to `wstool`, it doesn't really understand anything about them (it essentially 'forwards' commands to vcs binaries that do all the work) and doesn't introspect the repositories that it clones.

It also (somewhat) follows the KISS principle: what you want could be done using a `bash` one-liner.

But it would also seem to result in nested `.git` (or other vcs) checkouts, which is not really something recommended.

---

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but `vcstool`'s `import` verb does support git submodules:

```
  --recursive        Recurse into submodules (default: False)
```

and supports importing `.rosinstall` files.

Personally I don't like submodules at all, but it could provide an alternative approach.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-05**:
Then I'll make my own script! It's for [`ros_gitlab_ci`](https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/ros_gitlab_ci/)

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-06**:
Example bash function [here](https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/ros_gitlab_ci/-/blob/9b4724d728584c925512ed7fee711c28e3c3f4d6/gitlab-ros.bash#L124-141). Be careful because this function deletes the `rosinstall` files along the way, only use in CI environment!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
Can you comment on why you're not using `industrial_ci`? From reading the code of that script, it would seem to be doing what `industrial_ci` does (in a gitlab setup).

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-07**:
At the time I switched to GitLab `industrial_ci` was not compatible with GitLab CI. I like to be able to modify it on my own without waiting for someone to merge a request (usually takes weeks..). I could probably switch to `industrial_ci` but it would take a lot of time. And I would probably have

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-07**:
to re-implement some features that are missing in `industrial_ci`. Like being able to clone private repositories from GitLab using CI job tokens. `industrial_ci` uses SSH keys and the setup is MUCH more complicated.

I still think `ros_gitlab_ci` is simpler than `industrial_ci`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
It's simpler, yes, agreed. I was just curious, not trying to say that you should switch.

All alternative approaches to a common problem tend to converge towards similar solutions though.